# Apache Flink Stream to send messages to different sinks based on condition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a list of topics and I need to send messages to one of those topics, but based on some condition.

Assume that, producer is configured with a set of topics(lets say around 10 topics),
Can we do something like below in Apache-flink ?

```
if(condition1){
   send message to topic 1
} else if(condition2){
   send message to topic 2
}
//and so on
```

Note that I have one single source of messages(ie., single String-stream)
Below is the code that I am currently using.

```
                StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
                CustomSourceFunction source = CustomSourceFunction.getInstance();
                DataStream<String> stringStream = env.addSource(source);
                FlinkKafkaProducer011<String> producer = getProducer();
                stringStream.addSink(producer);
                env.execute();
```

Is there a way to configure a no of sinks based on some conditions in apache-flink ?
Also, how many sinks can be added to the same stream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any limits for number of sinks.

Since Flink 14 there is `.setTopicSelector((element) -> {<your-topic-selection-logic>})` method in [kafka Serializer](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#serializer) but your code looks like older version. I think there is many ways to achieve your goal, one of them to
apply your topic selection logic in `ProducerRecord` during serialization.

```
    /**
     * Create a record with no key
     * 
     * @param topic The topic this record should be sent to
     * @param value The record contents
     */
    public ProducerRecord(String topic, V value) {
        this(topic, null, null, null, value, null);
    }
```

Or maybe it will be easier to just filter your stream and create a specific producers/sinks for different cases. Also maybe [side outputs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/) will work for you.

Comment: The topic selection logic in the ```setRecordSerializer``` worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flink's [SideOutput](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/) to achieve this. You can also find an example of the implementation in Immerok's Flink cookbook at https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/splitting-apache-kafka-events-to-different-outputs-with-apache-flink/

Disclaimer: I work for Immerok